# Code for two worksheet change events which I have combined not working

Tags: vba, excel

Having looked for an answer to my question, I am at a loss and need some help.  I have two different worksheet change events in the same worksheet which will be triggered by two entirely separate cell's changing condition (one is empty to not empty to trigger an Unlock range event, and the second is a change in value which will trigger a series of hide cell events based on the value it has changed to.  (the second works perfectly on its own, but the first doesn't.) I have obviously missed something or my code is mince, and I need help

here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "D5" Then
Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "": Range("A6:D115").Locked = True
    Case IsNot = Empty: Range("C6:D6,A16:D16,C19:D22,D25:D25,D41:D57,B58:D58,C63:D63,C65:D73,C75:D78,C80:D84,D88:D88,A93:D98,D101:D103,B113:B114,D113:D113").Locked = False
End Select
End If

If Target.Address(False, False) = "D25" Then
Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Select as appropriate": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case "USA - Breen Road": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("45:45,47:47,53:57,77:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "USA - Conroe": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("40:52,77:78,80:80,85:85").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "USA - Lafayette": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("43:43,45:47,49:49,53:57,61:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Europe - Aberdeen": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Europe - Gateshead": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("53:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Middle East - Dubai": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Middle East - Saudi Arabia": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("43:43,45:47,50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Middle East - All": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - Loyang": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("41:41,44:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - Tuas": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - All": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("41:41,44:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Perth - Australia": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Range("41:57,63:63,67:67,72:72,74:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
End If

End Sub
```

I have the cells all set to locked and the sheet protected - to prevent cells I don't want to have data in them, being fiddled with.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"not working"* is the worst error description you can use. Please instead always **describe** what happens: Eg. do you get any error messages if so which and what line? What do you expect your code should do and what does it do instead?

Comment: Google basic syntax documentation before posting here... https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Case IsNot = Empty
```

is not valid syntax.

Change to

```
Case Is <> ""
```

Comment: Thanks Scott I will have a look at this and feedback.

Comment: Hi Scott,  I tried you correction, but something else must be awry as I cannot get the two pieces of code to work.  The second section is fine, and in the end I changed my spreadsheet to remove the need for the first bit of code.  Thanks anyway.